# Encoded number sign ("%23") in URL path

Tags: apex, url

How would you add `#` in the URL via passing from PageReference? I have tried few different way but that does not work.

```
public PageReference clickOnName() 
{ 
    PageReference newPage = Page.NewEmployee; 
    newPage.getParameters().put('empId', empId + '#menu');  
    return newPage.setRedirect(true); 
}
```

The above URL will be something:

```
http://xxxxx.visual.force.com/apex/NewEmployee?id=ABC%23menu
```

Instead I want:

```
http://xxxxx.visual.force.com/apex/NewEmployee?id=ABC#menu
```

Comment: Why do you think setting a parameter is likely to do something other than setting the parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Map#setAnchor instead:

```
PageReference newPage = Page.NewEmployee; 
newPage.getParameters().put('empId', empId);
newPage.setAnchor('menu');  
return newPage.setRedirect(true);
```

Comment: 1+ I did not aware of the `setAnchor` thanks for that... able to add anchor to the URL but my page is white blank after it redirects any thoughts?

Comment: @NickKahn Off the top of my head, not sure. Did you check your console for any errors? Developer Console debug logs? Are you using an iframe to display your page?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console logs and the weird thing is that if I hit ENTER on the URL then the page loads property with anchor tag selected.

Comment: another test I did was not adding `setAnchor` and after it redirecting I see the page but when add `setAnchor` after it redirects I get white blank page.

Comment: @NickKahn Hmm. It works for me when I tested it using a simple mockup. I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: @NickKahn I think we may need to see a more complete example, so this might be a good time for you to see if you can create an example that exhibits this behavior and ask a new question. I'm not able to replicate your issue.

Comment: fair enough! will spend some time debugging and if I could not able to fix then I will post the new question.